# How can I temporarily disable a MATLAB toolbox

Tags: matlab

I have a standalone license for MATLAB R2016b with the Parallel Toolbox. I am writing an application that will be sent out to customers who may not have that toolbox installed and I would like to write my application so that it fails gracefully (i.e. runs single threaded). The problem is that since I have the toolbox installed, I never get an error when I try to use a parallel toolbox function, so I can't test the failure points.

To generalize the situation, I would like to be able to test the behavior of an application when a toolbox dependency is not met so I can either provide a meaningful message to the user for why they can't use my application or else provide a workaround.

Is there any way, short of repeatedly uninstalling and then reinstalling the toolbox, or else buying a second license and installing on a second computer (or the same computer with a different username), to temporarily make MATLAB think that it isn't available?

---

From the comments to the question, it appears the answer to my question is "no". Simply removing the path does not disable the toolbox. First of all, the toolbox is not in a single directory, it is in several (I had to `rmpath` 11 directories for Parallel Toolbox and I don't really know if I got them all).

Once that was done, typing in `ver` still shows that the Parallel Toolbox is installed. It also throws *different errors*, and so this method cannot be used to adequately test the behavior in my program. For instance, after I removed the directories, I get the following behavior:

```
>> n = gpuDeviceCount
Undefined function or variable 'gpuDeviceCount'.
```

but when I asked a friend, who does not have the parallel toolbox installed, to type in the same command, he got the following:

```
>> gpuDeviceCount
gpuDeviceCount is not included in your installed products. These products offer 'gpuDeviceCount':
  Parallel Computing Toolbox
```

Different errors, different exceptions thrown. The second one is expected and if I could easily and deliberately throw that error, I could see what exception to test for in a try/catch block and behave appropriately. The first is unexpected and could happen for any number of reasons such as a corrupt install or a stupid typo on my part (e.g. with the paths added back, `n = gpuDeviceCounts;` still throws the first error).

---

I will submit a ticket to MathWorks and update the question if I hear back unless someone has another workaround.

Comment: delete the folder to the toolbox (generally under `/PATH/TO/MATLAB/toolbox`) in you path

Comment: And then what do I do when I want to turn the toolbox back on?

Comment: Add it back to the path in the same session, or do nothing if you are going to restart.

Comment: You can do that calling `rmpath(path_to_tbx)` and `addpath(path_to_tbx)`, or in GUI by click `Set Path` from the top menu.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/118774

Comment: Just stop paying the license and MathWorks will do the rest :)

Comment: If you have just a bit more patience, I'm throwing together a nice utility for this, which I will place on the [File Exchange](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/).

Comment: That would be fantastic! I did already submit a feature request with MathWorks this morning, but I know that those wheels will move very slowly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

I'll post this on the FEX, and after it's approved, I'll place a link to it here.

**EDIT 1** they approved my submission, which can be found [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/60347-rodyo-fex-toggletoolbox) or directly from [my GitHub](https://github.com/rodyo/FEX-toggleToolbox). <strike>I'll remove the code from this post.</strike> (actually, I'll leave it in, because that would turn the answer into a link-only reply, as rightfully remarked by Andy Clifton).

I've tested this **only** on R2010a, where it passes all my unit tests. But experience shows that MATLAB may do *very* different things from version to version, so if you find a problem, get a strange error, etc., please tell me, so I can make repairs.

For now, here's version 1.0:

```
% TOGGLETOOLBOX      Utility to switch MATLAB toolboxes on or off.
%
% S = TOGGLETOOLBOX()
% S = TOGGLETOOLBOX('')
% S = TOGGLETOOLBOX('all') queries the on/off states of all installed
% toolboxes.
%
% M = TOGGLETOOLBOX('names') returns the full names / directory names map
% [M] applicable to the current MATLAB installation.
%
% S = TOGGLETOOLBOX(toolbox, state) queries or sets the on/off state of the
% MATLAB toolbox [toolbox] to [state]. The string or cellstring [toolbox] may
% be equal to the toolbox' installation directory name (the same as used by
% ver()), or the toolbox' full name. The string [state] may be one of 'on',
% 'off' or 'query'. The return argument [S] is a structure containing the
% toolbox name(s) as fields, with the on/off state represented as true/false.
%
% S = TOGGLETOOLBOX(..., permanency) for string [permanency] equal to
% 'permanent' will attempt to make the change persist between different
% MATLAB sessions. For [permanency] equal to 'temporary' (the default), the
% change will only last for the remainder of the current session.
%
% TOGGLETOOLBOX(S0) will reset the on/off states of all toolboxes to the
% states contained in [S0], where [S0] is a structure previously returned by
% TOGGLETOOLBOX() as outlined above.
%
% Disabling a toolbox is done by removing the relevant directories from the
% MATLAB path. Since the order of the path is important for name resolution,
% TOGGLETOOLBOX() attempts to keep the order of all paths as close to MATLAB's
% startup path as possible. Calling TOGGLETOOLBOX() multiple times for different
% toolboxes and arbitrary on/off states should not affect the overall path
% order -- calling TOGGLETOOLBOX('all', 'on') afterwards results in a path
% identical to the startup path.
%
% Note that TOGGLETOOLBOX() generates a MAT file for both performance and
% permanence between MATLAB sessions. Please make sure that TOGGLETOOLBOX()
% is located in a directory with write access.
%
%
% EXAMPLE SESSION:
%
%     >> M = toggleToolbox('names')%
%     M =
%         'aero'             'Aerospace Toolbox'
%         'aeroblks'         'Aerospace Blockset'
%         'bioinfo'          'Bioinformatics Toolbox'
%         'comm'             'Communications Toolbox'
%         ...
%
%    >> S = toggleToolbox({'Aerospace Toolbox' 'Wavelet Toolbox'}, 'query')
%    S =
%           aero: 1
%        wavelet: 1
%
%    >> w = ver('wavelet')
%    w =
%           Name: 'Wavelet Toolbox'
%        Version: '4.5'
%        Release: '(R2010a)'
%           Date: '25-Jan-2010'
%
%    >> S = toggleToolbox({'Aerospace Toolbox' 'Wavelet Toolbox'}, 'off');
%    >> toggleToolbox({'Aerospace Toolbox' 'Wavelet Toolbox'}, 'query')
%    ans =
%           aero: 0
%        wavelet: 0
%
%    >> w = ver('wavelet')
%    w =
%    0x0 struct array with fields:
%        Name
%        Version
%        Release
%        Date
%
%    >> toggleToolbox(S);
%    >> toggleToolbox({'Aerospace Toolbox' 'Wavelet Toolbox'}, 'query')
%    ans =
%           aero: 1
%        wavelet: 1
%
%    >> % Cross-platform developer mode:
%    >> S = toggleToolbox('all', 'off');
%
% See also ver, verLessThan, matlabroot, warning.
function varargout = toggleToolbox(varargin)

    %% Initialize
    % ====================================================

    % Default msg ID for error/warning messages
    msgId = mfilename();

    % Store toolbox states in a store file
    storefile = fullfile(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')), ...
                         'toolbox_states.mat');


    % Names should be given as directory names, but who on Earth
    % knows those by heart? Therefore, we create a dirname/fullname
    % map, to allow users to enter the full toolbox name as well
    tb_name_map = get_tb_name_map();

    % Parse and check arguments to determine mode of operation 
    restoremode = false;
    querymode   = false;

    toolbox   = 'all';
    state     = 'on';
    permanent = 'temporary';

    switch nargin
        case 0
            % return states of ALL toolboxes
            querymode = true;

        case 1

            % Reset states
            if isstruct(varargin{1})

                restoremode = true;
                state       = 'restore';

                toolbox_states = varargin{1};

                assert(nargout == 0,...
                      [msgId ':argoutcount_error'], ...
                      '%s for single input argument does not have any output arguments.',...
                      mfilename);

                assert(isfield(toolbox_states, 'path') && ...
                       all(isfield(toolbox_states, tb_name_map(:,1))),...
                       [msgId ':invalid_tbstates_structure'], ...
                       'Input argument does not appear to be a structure generated by %s.',...
                       mfilename);

            % Query state of single toolbox
            elseif ischar(varargin{1})

                % Return toolbox names map
                if strcmpi(varargin{1}, 'names')
                    varargout{1} = tb_name_map;
                    return;

                % query mode
                else
                    querymode = true;
                    toolbox   = varargin{1};
                    state     = 'query';
                end
            end

        case 2
            % Toggle state of one or more toolboxes
            toolbox   = varargin{1};
            state     = varargin{2};
            querymode = strcmpi(state, 'query');


        case 3
            toolbox   = varargin{1};
            state     = varargin{2};
            querymode = strcmpi(state, 'query');

            if ~querymode
                permanent = varargin{3};
            else
                warning([msgId ':permanence_na_in_querymode'],...
                        'Permanency flag ignored for ''query'' mode.');
            end

        otherwise
            error([msgId ':argincount_error'],...
                  'Too many input arguments.');
    end

    % Cellstring of all paths makes for easier work
    paths = regexp(path, pathsep, 'split');

    % Initialize tb states structure
    if ~restoremode
        if exist(storefile,'file')==2
            % Load previous paths and toggle states, if any
            S = load(storefile);
            toolbox_states = S.toolbox_states;
            clear S;
        else
            % Otherwise, just initialize it by storing the previous
            % path strings...
            toolbox_states = struct('path', {paths});

            % ...and mark all toolboxes as "enabled"
            for ii = 1:size(tb_name_map,1)
                toolbox_states.(tb_name_map{ii,1}) = true; end

        end
    end

    % Some asserts
    assert(iscellstr(toolbox) || ischar(toolbox),...
           [msgId ':argument_error'], [...
           'Toolboxes must be given as a string (single toolbox) or a cell array of ',...
           'strings (multiple toolboxes).']);

    if ~restoremode
        assert(ischar(state) && any(strcmpi(state, {'on' 'off' 'query'})),...
               [msgId ':argument_error'],...
               'State must be a string equal to ''on'', ''off'' or ''query''.');
    end

    assert(ischar(permanent) && any(strcmpi(permanent, {'permanent', 'temporary'})),...
           [msgId ':argument_error'],...
           'Permanency must be indicated via string ''perpanent'' or ''temporary''.');


    % Apply name map
    if isempty(toolbox) || any(strcmpi(toolbox, 'all'))
        toolbox = tb_name_map(:,1);

    else
        if ~iscell(toolbox)
            toolbox = {toolbox}; end

        % Check names and perform lookups
        tb_name_map_i = cellfun(@lower, tb_name_map, 'UniformOutput', false);
        toolbox_i     = cellfun(@lower, toolbox,     'UniformOutput', false);

        dirs           = ismember(toolbox_i, tb_name_map_i(:,1));
        [isname,names] = ismember(toolbox_i, tb_name_map_i(:,2));

        assert(all(dirs | isname),...
               [msgId ':unknown_toolbox'],...
               'Toolbox: ''%s'' does not seem to be installed.',...
               toolbox{find( ~(dirs | isname), 1, 'first')});

        toolbox(isname) = tb_name_map(names(isname),1);
    end


    % Query mode: return current toggle states
    if querymode
        % ALL toolboxes
        if isempty(toolbox)
            save(storefile, 'toolbox_states');
            %toolbox_states = rmfield(toolbox_states, 'path');
            varargout{1}   = toolbox_states;

        % SOME toolboxes
        else
            for ii = 1:numel(toolbox)
                toolbox_state.(toolbox{ii}) = toolbox_states.(toolbox{ii}); end
            varargout{1} = toolbox_state;
        end
        return;
    end







    %% Toggle all requested toolboxes
    % ====================================================

    toolbox_states_out = toolbox_states;

    switch lower(state)

        case 'off'
            for ii = 1:numel(toolbox)

                tb = toolbox{ii};

                if isfield(toolbox_states, tb) && ~toolbox_states.(tb)
                    warning([msgId ':toolbox_already_switched_off'],...
                            'Toolbox ''%s'' already switched off; ignoring.',...
                            tb);
                else
                    % Remove whole toolbox from path
                    toolbox_states.(tb) = false;
                    inds  = ~cellfun('isempty', strfind(paths, fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', tb)));
                    rmpath(paths{inds});
                end

            end


        case {'on' 'restore'}

            switched = false;

            for ii = 1:numel(toolbox)

                tb = toolbox{ii};

                if ~isfield(toolbox_states, toolbox{ii})
                    warning([msgId ':toolbox_not_switched_off'],...
                            'Toolbox ''%s'' was not switched off; ignoring.',...
                            tb);
                else
                    switched = true;
                end

                % Just set toggle state
                toolbox_states.(tb) = true;

            end

            % Preserve path order:
            % - restore whole path
            % - then re-disable relevant toolboxes
            if switched

                newPaths = ~ismember(paths, toolbox_states.path);
                if ~any(newPaths)
                    % No new paths have been added
                    path( sprintf('%s;', toolbox_states.path{1:end-1}),...
                          toolbox_states.path{end} );
                    paths = toolbox_states.path;
                else
                    % TODO: wouldn't it be better to "simply" merge the paths?
                    warning([msgId ':new_paths_added'],[ ...
                            'New directories have been added to the path between consecutive ',...
                            '''on''/''off'' calls to %s. The path will be restored to that prior to ',...
                            'the first ''off'' call to %s, which will effectively remove these ',...
                            'new directories from the path.'],...
                            mfilename, mfilename);
                end

                toolboxes = fieldnames(toolbox_states);
                toolboxes = toolboxes(~strcmp(toolboxes, 'path'));

                for jj = 1:numel(toolboxes)
                    tb = toolboxes{jj};
                    if ~toolbox_states.(tb)
                        inds  = ~cellfun('isempty', strfind(paths, fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', tb)));
                        rmpath(paths{inds});
                    end
                end

            end

    end

    %% Finish up
    % ====================================================

    % Save toggle states and previous paths
    save(storefile, 'toolbox_states');

    % Make changes permanent when requested
    switch lower(permanent)
        case 'temporary'
            % noop; the default
        case 'permanent'
            savepath();
    end

    if ~restoremode
        varargout{1} = toolbox_states_out; end

end

function tb_name_map = get_tb_name_map()

    persistent tb_map
    if isempty(tb_map)

        disp('First call; collecting toolbox information. Please wait...');

        % Cellstring of all paths makes for easier work
        paths = regexp(path, pathsep, 'split');

        % Get list of toolbox directory names
        tbs = dir(fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox'));
        tbs = tbs(3:end);
        tb_dirnames = {tbs.name}';

        % Get the full toolbox names
        S(numel(tb_dirnames)) = struct('Name',    '',...
                                       'Version', '',...
                                       'Release', '',...
                                       'Date',    '');

        for ii = 1:numel(tb_dirnames)

            tb_dirname = tb_dirnames{ii};

            % Add toolbox (could have been removed from path, in which case
            % ver() will not find it)
            tb_dir = fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', tb_dirname);
            inds = ~cellfun('isempty', ...
                            strfind(paths, tb_dir));

            if ~any(inds)
                addpath(genpath(tb_dir)); end

            % Get toolbox information via ver()
            tb_version = ver(tb_dirname);
            if ~isempty(tb_version)
                S(ii) = tb_version; end

        end

        tb_fullnames = {S.Name}';

        % Some dirs may not be toolboxes; slice those off
        tb_slice = ~cellfun('isempty', tb_fullnames);

        tb_fullnames = tb_fullnames(tb_slice);
        tb_dirnames  = tb_dirnames (tb_slice);

        % Collect terms
        tb_map = [tb_dirnames tb_fullnames];

        % Reset path
        path(sprintf('%s;', paths{1:end-1}), paths{end});

    end

    tb_name_map = tb_map;

end
```

Comment: It works quite nicely in R2016b. The only strange behavior is that there is an undocumented function called `findUnlicensedFunctions.m` that MATLAB now calls to see if the function you called is in a particular toolbox. If it is, then it changes the console message to the second error message I put in my question above, pointing you to the missing toolbox. The underlying `MException` object seems to be the same, however.

Comment: @craigim hmmm...then it works, right? You get the same `ME` your friend got thrown, right?

Comment: Yes. The `ME` is the same. There is a difference in the console message, but not in the `ME.message`. That difference is handled (I believe) by this `findUnlicensedFunctions` function which intercepts the message, looks up the function in a database, and then returns the name of the missing toolbox. For the purpose of using and testing a `try/catch` block, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Please put the code back here! Link only answers are frowned upon because the material in the link can disappear.